# Class function member not depending on the class members

Tags: c++, oop

Is there a good reason why should a class function member be part of the class if it does not depend on any of the members of the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. In fact, [you should prefer free-functions over member functions](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197). Only functions that really need to operate on the members should be member functions, [the rest should use them to provide functionality](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm).

Comment: +1 thank you! I searched for this article to post it hear but couldn't find it!

Comment: "Only functions that really need to operate on the members should be member functions"... plus *virtual* functions, those only come as members ;)

Comment: @Fred: Er, yeah. And things like `operator[]` which has to be a member function, for whatever silly reason they came up with.

Comment: @GMan Agree :) I find it even more interesting the fact that `operator=` has to be a member function, while `operator+=` (similarly all other `X=`) can be implemented as free functions... You can try to defend that `operator[]` is there to *index* the object, so *operating* on the instance, it *has* to be a member, but `operator+=` is unarguably there to operate on the object and it can be a free function!

Comment: When exactly should the functions be which correlate to the meaning of the class? If in some Utility class, would it not potentially explode from the amount of source code in it?

Comment: @Leonid: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "does not depend on any *non-public* members", Scott Meyers once [answered a definite *no*](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197) to that question.

However, he focused only on encapsulation: encapsulation is improved by making those functions non-members.

Other considerations can, for example, include that you cannot call `operator<<` on a temporary if the operator is defined as a non-member. (Why would you ever want to do that? Well, for example to build up a string argument from constituent parts, iostream-style.)

And the considerations can include simply how natural and clear the usage notation is. The notation with nested calls (as for non-members) can be rather annoying and unclear. That's why we have `->` as syntactic sugar for `*` dereferencing + member selection.

So, if you focus only on encapsulation, then move those member functions out of class, as Scott Meyers adviced. And otherwise, make an engineering decision where aspects such as usability and notational clarity are also considered. Anyway, don't fret about it: it's probably not incredibly important. :-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @FredOverflow: thanks, but I've already fixed it. It's my search algorithm for link to that article. Go to Facebook, find old posting by Prasoon where he referenced the article. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If its correlated with the meaning of the class, you should put it together even if it do not use any member of the Class.

The reason it for simply the development, and for a future developer know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

It often happens when overriding a virtual function.  If the base class has a pure virtual along the lines of getWidgetCount(), for example, and your derived class doesn't support widgets, it would just return 0.

Answer (score 0):

the most common case concern utility classes for example if i have to develop functions to convert BSTR to string and vice versa , i can create a class with static methods.

it's useful to package functions concerning the same area in the same class, another solution is to package them in the same namespace, but unfortunatly namespaces are not very used even in the well known c++ librairies.

and for other cases adding method to a class with no relation with other members increase the lack of cohesion and the metric LCOM will be high, and the design will be impacted.